# Change text color of commented program code?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm looking for a simple feature or work-around that can highlight commented program code as opposed to technical notes.  Is there such a feature or other way to do it?

I want this to appear in light gray, as normal:

```
//avoids a ClassCastException. See bugfix #123
```

I want this to appear in orange so that it can safely be removed (the history for which would be under version control):

```
//public static void method() {
//}
```

I searched SO but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in IntelliJ Idea. Fortunately, there is even better way to avoid commented-out sections of code in your project.

The best option is to use Static Code Analysis tool such as [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) - it has a rule which detects commented-out lines of code and reports the issue to you. After running such tool you can be certain you have no commented-out dead code in your project.

See the post about [Commented-out code eradication with Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/commented-out-code-eradication-with-sonar/).

Comment: Seems a bit heavy just for one feature, but will take a look

Comment: The advantage is that commented out code is just one of dozens of code smells that those tools help you to automatically detect, making your code much cleaner overall.